# 1 dimensional and 2 dimensional array

Tags: c

if I have a single dimensional array, let's call it A and a 2 dimensional array let's call it B.

int A[5], B[5][3];

is it possible to write a code to get (A[0]=B[0][0]+B[0][1]+B[0][2])/3 and so forth until A[5} ?
How do I do it ?

Comment: It is possible - use your keyboard + skills + text editor. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<5; i++) A[i] = (B[i][0]+B[i][1]+B[i][2])/3;`

Comment: Given the definition `int A[5]`, performing the requested assignment for `A[5]` would be inappropriate; the last element of `A` is `A[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

so, something like this ?

```
for(int i=0; i<6;i++)
  { 
    A[i]=0;
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    A[i]+=B[i][j];

     A[i]=A[i]/3;
   }
```

I think this will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use two for loops?

```
for (a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
        A[a] += B[a][b];
    }
}
```

Then do your division.

Or is it more complicated than that?

With appropriate initialisation!

Comment: `a < 4` should be `a < 5` (or `a < 6`, depending on which part of the question is wrong).

Comment: @EricPostpischil is right, but with a proper `A[a] = 0` at the right place your answer is good.

Comment: Just making sure everyone was paying attention:-)